# I Want to find a specific element in the array of firstChild

Tags: javascript

I am storing all the anchor tags in "totalLinks"

```
var totalLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var listOfFirsChildOfAnchorTag = [];
```

Here I am storing all the firstchild elements in an array

```
for(i=0;i<totalLinks.length;i++)
{
  currentFirsChildOfAnchorTag = totalLinks[i].firstChild;
  listOfFirsChildOfAnchorTag.push(currentFirsChildOfAnchorTag);
}
```

Now I want to find whether a span element is the first child of anchor tag or not. How can I find it from the above array.

If You know another method of doing the same thing please suggest that.

Comment: Do you want to know if span element is in the array? Or do you wish to know the index of the span as well?

Comment: @snit80 I want to know that whether span elements exist in the array or not and if it exist then I want to know its index as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `firstChild` returns text and comments as well, you should start by checking if it's an element by using [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

```
totalLinks[i].firstChild.nodeType === 1
```

Then you'd check if the `tagName` was `"span"`

```
totalLinks[i].firstChild.tagName.toLowerCase() === "span"
```

so

```
if ( totalLinks[i].firstChild.nodeType === 1 &&
     totalLinks[i].firstChild.tagName.toLowerCase() === "span"
   ) {
   // ...
}
```

you could also just get all direct children of anchors that are spans and the first child

```
var listOfFirsChildOfAnchorTag = document.querySelectorAll('a > span:first-child')
```